# C++ template type specification

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

I have an empty class with the same name as a blank function. When I try to pass this class as a template parameter I receive an error:

"*type/value mismatch at argument 1*"

"*'Test' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'*"

Consider:

```
#include <vector>

void Test() {
}

class Test {
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Test> test;
}
```

Changing to

```
std::vector<class Test>
```

seems to work, but I was not able to found out, whether this is required by a standard, or just randomly supported by my compiler.

**Can someone point out, how to solve this issue or link to standard, that requires this behavior?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you have to use the keyword `class` prepended to the name for disambiguation, which resulting in an elaborated type specifier.

[[class.name]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.name#2):

(emphasis mine)

> If a class name is declared in a scope where a variable, function, or
>   enumerator of the same name is also declared, then when both
>   declarations are in scope, **the class can be referred to only using an
>   elaborated-type-specifier** ([basic.lookup.elab]). [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct stat {
>   // ...
> };
>
> stat gstat;                     // use plain stat to define variable
>
> int stat(struct stat*);         // redeclare stat as function
>
> void f() {
>   struct stat* ps;              // struct prefix needed to name struct stat
>   stat(ps);                     // call stat()
> }
> ```
>
> — end example ]

And [[dcl.type.elab]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.elab#nt:elaborated-type-specifier):

> *elaborated-type-specifier:*
>
> - *class-key attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> nested-name-specifier<sub>opt</sub> identifier*
> - *class-key simple-template-id*
> - *class-key nested-name-specifier* template<sub>*opt*</sub> *simple-template-id*
> - enum *nested-name-specifier<sub>opt</sub> identifier*